# Trying, without success, to use a new socket after closing the old one

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, connection-refused

for a classwork i've to close all opened sockets after client sends "NEWPORT " and assign the "n-port" to a new socket, and from that moment i've to use the socket created for the new incoming connections, but when i try to connect to new one the perror function on client side says me "Connection refused".

Server code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 512

void manage_connections(int fds,struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, struct sockaddr_in cl_addr, socklen_t cl_len);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cl_addr;
    socklen_t cl_len;
    int fds=0;

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5200);

    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    fds = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(fds<0){

        perror("Socket error");

        exit(-1);

    }

    if(bind(fds,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0){

        perror("Bind error");

        exit(-1);

    }

    if((listen(fds,5))<0){

        perror("Listen error");

        exit(-1);

    }

    manage_connections(fds,serv_addr, cl_addr, cl_len);

    close(fds);

    return 0;

}

void manage_connections(int fds,struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, struct sockaddr_in cl_addr, socklen_t cl_len){

    char buffer[MAX_SIZE], cl_ip[MAX_SIZE], cl_port[MAX_SIZE], cmd_np[MAX_SIZE], cmd_np_n[MAX_SIZE], cmd_np_str[MAX_SIZE], nport[MAX_SIZE];

    int i=0, port=0,fdc=0, nfds;

    struct sockaddr_in nserv_addr;

    while(1){

        cl_len = sizeof(cl_addr);

        fdc = accept(fds, (struct sockaddr*)&cl_addr, &cl_len);

        if(fdc<0){

            perror("Accept error");

            exit(-1);

        }

        do{

            for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){

                buffer[i]=0;

                cl_ip[i]=0;

                cl_port[i]=0;

                cmd_np[i]=0;

                cmd_np_n[i]=0;

                cmd_np_str[i]=0;

                nport[i]=0;

            }

            read(fdc,buffer, MAX_SIZE);

            if(strcmp(buffer,"MYIP")==0){

                strcat(cl_ip,inet_ntoa(cl_addr.sin_addr));

                write(fdc,cl_ip,strlen(cl_ip));

            } else if(strcmp(buffer,"MYPORT")==0){

                sprintf(cl_port,"%d", (int)htons(cl_addr.sin_port));

                write(fdc, cl_port, strlen(cl_port));

            }else{

                sscanf(buffer, "%s %d", cmd_np, &port);

                sprintf(nport, "%d", port);

                if(strcmp(cmd_np,"NEWPORT")==0){

                    strcat(cmd_np_str, "ACK ");

                    strcat(cmd_np_str, nport);

                    write(fdc, cmd_np_str,strlen(cmd_np_str));

                    close(fds);

                    close(fdc);

                    nserv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

                    nserv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

                    nserv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

                    nfds = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);

                    if(nfds<0){

                        perror("New socket error");

                        exit(-1);

                    }

                    if((bind(nfds,(struct sockaddr*)&nserv_addr,sizeof(nserv_addr)))<0){

                        perror("New bind error");

                        exit(-1);

                    }

                    if((listen(nfds,5))<0){

                        perror("New listen error");

                        exit(-1);

                    }

                    manage_connections(nfds,nserv_addr, cl_addr, cl_len);

                }

            }

        }while(strcmp(cmd_np,"NEWPORT")!=0);

        close(fdc);

    }


}
```

Client code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 512

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct sockaddr_in cl_addr;
    int fdc=0,len=0, res_len=0,i=0;
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE];

    cl_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    cl_addr.sin_port = htons(5200);

    inet_aton("192.168.10.128",&cl_addr.sin_addr);

    fdc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(fdc<0){

        perror("Accept error");

        exit(-1);

    }

    if((connect(fdc, (struct sockaddr*)&cl_addr, sizeof(cl_addr)))<0){

        perror("Connect error");

        exit(-1);

    }

    while(1){

        write(1, "Inserire uno tra i comandi MYIP, MYPORT, NEWPORT:\n", strlen("Inserire uno tra i comandi MYIP, MYPORT, NEWPORT:\n"));

        len = read(1, buffer, MAX_SIZE);

        buffer[len-1] = '\0';

        write(fdc, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);

        for(i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++)

            buffer[i]=0;

        res_len = read(fdc,buffer,MAX_SIZE);

        write(1,"\nResponso: ",strlen("\nResponso: "));

        write(1, buffer, res_len);

        write(1,"\n",strlen("\n"));

    }

    close(fdc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Complete error checking of *all* relevant function calls, supported by detailed logging is debugging for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client is hard-coded to the 5200 port number. If you use `NEWPORT` to switch the server to a new one, the server will no longer be listening on 5200 since you're closing the original listening socket and opening a new one.

Hence when you run your client again, it gets Connection Refused *because* there's now nobody listening on the socket you're connecting to.

The best fix I see is to add the ability to specify a port number as a command line argument on the client side.

Other issues with your code:

1. You're assuming that you will send the entire buffer content on each call to `write` and that you will receive the entire buffer content on every `read`. In a toy program like this, that will work, but is not guaranteed by TCP.
2. Your `manage_connections` function is recursive which seems a poor structure. Enough invocations and you would run out of stack.
3. There's no built-in way to exit your client program. You can press Ctrl-C to abort, but it doesn't detect that the server just closed the connection (because it's reading from the terminal) in the `NEWPORT` case.
4. You're actually *reading* from the standard *output* file. That typically works if you're connected to a terminal, but would not work in other scenarios and is not a good thing to rely on.
5. You're passing the `cl_addr` and `cl_len` variables into `manage_connections` but that's pointless. The caller doesn't initialize them before or use them after the call. They should just be declared inside the function.